# Catch Lock Screen Event

Tags: android, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

Good day. I am writing in C ++ Builder in Embarcadero Xe8. I do mobile application project on Ios and android and faced such problem: I can not catch the phone lock screen event. I used to always do so:

```
    bool TForm1::HandleApp(TApplicationEvent a, TObject *x)
{
    if (a == TApplicationEvent::EnteredBackground)
    {
        MediaPlayer1->Stop();
    }
    return true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  _di_IFMXApplicationEventService a;
   if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXApplicationEventService), &a))
   {
    a->SetApplicationEventHandler(TForm1::HandleApp);
   }
}
```

But an error:

> \Unit1.cpp(33): cannot initialize a parameter of type 'TApplicationEventHandler' (aka 'bool (**closure *)(Fmx::Platform::TApplicationEvent, System::TObject __borland_class *__strong) __attribute**((pcs("aapcs-vfp")))') with an lvalue of type 'bool (__closure *)(Fmx::Platform::TApplicationEvent, System::TObject __borland_class *__strong)'
>   FMX.Platform.hpp(252): passing argument to parameter 'AEventHandler' here

I Do not know what else to try to do! Could you please help me?

Comment: On a side note, you should NOT be using the `OnCreate` event in C++. It is a Delphi idiom that can produce illegal behaviour in C++. Override the class constructor instead (`__fastcall TForm1(TComponent*)`).

Answer (score 0):

Your `HandleApp()` method is missing the `__fastcall` calling convention:

```
bool __fastcall  TForm1::HandleApp(TApplicationEvent a, TObject *x)
```

Also, your call to `SetApplicationEventHandler()` needs to be like this instead:

```
a->SetApplicationEventHandler(&HandleApp);
```

This is important because the event handler is a `__closure`, so it carries two pointers inside of it - a pointer to the class method to call, and a pointer to the object instance that the method is called on (the `this` value of the method). When you pass the handler by class name only, the compiler doesn't know which object instance to act on, and thus cannot populate the `__closure`.  The syntax above allows the compiler to see that `HandleApp` should be associated with the `Form1` object.